# Assign a variable in a bash script dynamically that parses a os path

Tags: bash, variables

I seem to be not able to get this right
When i run this code I need a variable for the filename later on. How should I do thi?

```
#!/bin/bash

foo="../../../data/audio/serval-data/wav-16bit-16khz/ytdl/balanced_train/vidzyGjrJfE_rg.wav"

echo $foo
echo "${foo%.*}" | cut -d "/" -f10;

# fid=vidzyGjrJfE_rg
```

I want to use new variable fid to have value "vidzyGjrJfE_rg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a couple of iterations of shell builtins for this (see [@melpomene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52030055/1745001)) but FYI that's exactly what `basename` exists to do:

```
$ foo="../../../data/audio/serval-data/wav-16bit-16khz/ytdl/balanced_train/vidzyGjrJfE_rg.wav"
$ fid=$(basename "$foo" '.wav')
$ echo "$fid"
vidzyGjrJfE_rg
```

Comment: Note, however, that this version has to spawn two extra processes (a subshell and `basename`), so my version that does simple string manipulation is probably faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
fid="${foo##*/}"
fid="${fid%.*}"
```

Just as `%` removes a matching suffix from a variable, `#` removes a prefix (and `##` removes the longest matching prefix). See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion.

Comment: I'd do those in the opposite order (remove path prefix, *then* filename extension). That way if the filename doesn't have an extension, it won't trim to the last "/../" in the path part.